# Dynamic Nuxt content fetching depending of the path

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I have a folder structure in my nuxt project like this:

```
...
/pages/_slug.vue
/content
  /report
    page1.json
    /doc
      page2.json
```

In my pages folder I have a _slug.vue file

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ profile.hello }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $content, params }) {
    const profile = await $content('report', params.slug, { deep: true }).fetch()
    return { profile }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I visit `/page1` all works fine, however when I request `/doc/page2` no page is being rendered. Now I am confused since I added `{ deep:true }` to achieve this behavior but this doesn't work. How can I make sure that the folder structure resembles my routes?

Comment: What is the content of `params.slug` when you're on `/doc/page2`? Should it be `'page2'` or `'/doc/page2'`?

Comment: It should be '/doc/page2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `pages/_.vue` and write this content in it, it should work properly

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ profile.hello }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, route }) {
    const profile = await $content('report', route.fullPath, { deep: true }).fetch()
    return { profile }
  },
}
</script>
```

This is working because of the usage of [`Unknown Dynamic Nested Routes`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes).

---

This solution is using the following pattern of `$content('articles', params.slug)` and converting it into `/articles/${params.slug}` as shown in the part of the [documentation](https://content.nuxtjs.org/fetching#contentpath-options).

Comment: If my content json file would always be the same, let's say page.json, how can I modify this such that at / I see report/page.json and at /doc report/doc/page.json?

Comment: @JeremyKnees a condition/`swtich` followed by an interpolation of the `params.slug` is a good way to solve this.

Comment: Actually, the solution I was looking for just needed a ```$content('report', route.fullPath, 'page', { deep: true }).fetch()```. Thanks anyway! You helped a ton :)

Comment: @JeremyKnees hm, didn't know. Nice find!